# Error While Compiling this C++ code

Tags: c++

I got the following error wwhile compiling this c++ code . What can be the reason behind this ?

```
     # include <iostream>
     # include <stdio.h>
     # include <conio.h>

     using namespace std;

     class Foo
     {
      int a;
      public :
      virtual void Fun1(); 

      Foo()
      {a=5;}
     };

     Class X: public Foo   // Error class does not name a type
     {
      Foo f;
      public:
      void Fun1() { }       
      X()
      {
       memset(&f,0x0,sizeof(f));
      }
     };

     int main()
     {
      X x; // Error 'X undeclared and expected ; before x, i guess because of first one
      getch();
      return 0;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `class` begins with a lower-case `c`. That will fix the errors you reported, but more errors remain.

You declare `Foo::Fun1`, but don't define it.

Finally you'll need to include `<cstring>` for the declaration of `std::memset`. It's possible that another header is including it indirectly, but you can't rely on that.

You'll then have undefined runtime behaviour, since it's not valid to use `memset` to overwrite non-POD objects - `Foo` has a virtual function, and so is not POD.

Comment: I corrected the case error but still While Compiling i get some linker error . Is it due to memset code that i am using ? Can you explain that . I have also defined the Fun1() {cout << "LOL" ;} in class X but still compilation error.

Comment: There shouldn't be a link error if you've defined `Foo::Fun1`. What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Ritesh: You'll get that error if you haven't defined `Foo::Fun1` (or perhaps if there's another virtual function that you haven't defined). Are you sure you've defined it?

Comment: I guess your answer :-You'll then have undefined runtime behaviour, since it's not valid to use memset to overwrite non-POD objects - Foo has a virtual function, and so is not POD. Is very correct the only thing is me getting a compiler linking error instead of Run time error

Comment: @Ritesh: I just noticed in your first comment, you say you defined `X::Fun1`. You need to define `Foo::Fun1` as well to fix the link error.

Comment: Yes , now after defining the virtual function the linker error goes . So does that mean that We can now use memset on virtual pointer as you said about non -POD objects ?

Answer (score 2):

The `Class` should be `class`.

Answer (score 1):

`Class X: public Foo` should be `class X: public Foo`, which should fix both errors.

Answer (score 1):

C++ language is case sensitive and requires its keywords to be written in lowercase. `class` is valid C++ keyword but `Class` is not. Rename `Class` to `class` when declaring class X.

Answer (score 0):

`Class X` is named with capital C. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your error really starts with the:
`Class X: public Foo   // Error class does not name a type`
`Class` must be `class`.